# Calculating and plotting variance and expected value

Tags: matlab

I am getting a histogram. I want to compute the standard deviation and expected value of the given histogram. Which matlab function will help me to do that? Secondly I want to show the variance and expected value over the histogram as shown in the figure below. How can I embed these lines over this histogram?

My histogram plots values v/s their probabilities...

[image]

This is my code plotting histogram:

```
   edges = unique(columnB)



  n_elements =histc(columnB, edges)/numel(columnB);

  c_elements =(n_elements)

  figure(2)
  bar(edges,c_elements,'BarWidth',4)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For evaluating the values of mean and std:

```
meanB=mean(columnB);   % expectation
stdB=std(columnB);     % std
```

For adding it to your plot:

```
figure(2)
hold on
ylim=get(gca,'ylim')
line([meanB meanB], ylim,'color','g')
hold on
line [meanB+stdB meanB+stdB NaN meanB-stdB meanB-stdB] , [ylim NaN ylim], 'color','r')
```

will give you green line for mean and red lines for std

Comment: line ([meanB+stdB meanB+stdB NaN meanB-stdB meanB-stdB] , [ylim NaN ylim],'r')    it says ??? Error using ==> line
String argument is an unknown option.

Error in ==> read at 25
line([meanB meanB], ylim,'g')

Comment: I'm not with my matlab right now, and wrote it without checking. The problem can be in the definition of `ylim`, i don't sure. Maybe someone here can run it, and catch the problem...

Comment: Oh, it's should be run while your figure(2) is open, by the line you wrote in your question.

Comment: I didn't run it, but it seems ok. besides that `c_elements` is unnecessary